# Express Hopfield-style energy sum as matrices

Tags: matrices, summation

I'm trying to express a Hopfield-style energy as matrices:
[Hopfield-style energy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue43V.png)

The equation in the link can be written as:

[Hopfield-style energy matrix form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBQrw.png)

I'm trying to calculate partial derivatives of the energy d/p_i E(p), but c in the equations is also a function of p_i, c_i = lambda * e^(-p_i*ln(p_i)), so the sum can be written as:

[expanded form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZLdc.png)

How do I write the last sum in [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZLdc.png) also as matrices?